# Angular Typeerror Cannot read property get of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was reading other stackoverflow articles and changing code but I cannot seem to understand this

```
angular.module('app')
          .controller('DefaultCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { }])
```

**Factory is the problem**

```
.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function ($scope, $http) {
    return {
        getSource: function($scope) {
            $http.get("GetPersonInfoFromRegister/T")
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.countries = data;
                });
        }
```

This Directive is fine, I am trying to modify the factory to return data from ajax call from a static return

```
.directive('autoComplete', function (autoCompleteDataService) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        // elem is a jquery lite object if jquery is not present,
        // but with jquery and jquery ui, it will be a full jquery object.
        debugger;
        elem.autocomplete({
            source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), //from your service
            minLength: 1
        });
    }
};
});

    }

}])
```

The factory was working when I was using an example and just returning

```
return ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
```

Comment: `$http` is async, and returns a promise.  in your case, it isn't even returning anything at all, rather it is setting `$scope.countries` to a value.  Your directive seems to be expecting a return value, not a property on `$scope` to be set.

Comment: What does it seems like I need to change in order to return the data from the web api call?

Comment: $http.get("GetPersonInfoFromRegister/T")  it throws error   get of undefined at Object.getSource

Comment: it's not the `$http.get` that is throwing the error, it is the fact that the `getSource` function you defined doesn't return anything.